# What is the proper way to restrict the access of some data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on an application where each employee have there own customers. 
When an employee wants to display, modifiy or delete a customer, I want to ensure that this customer is one of this employee. That's because of the url to do those actions are like

`www.xxx.com/customers/update/{idCustomer}`

The way I valid the access to the customer for now is with a service call (with database access) to ensure this customer is one of this employee.
This application is written in Spring MVC with Spring Security. I would like to know if there is a better way to do the same restriction access?

Comment: This is rather broad for a SO question... It looks like the Spring security answer to your problem is domain object security with ACLs and ACEs. You put on domain objects almost the same authorizations levels that you find on files in a decent file system, and controls them with method annotations. It may not be the simplest part of Spring Security but really powerful.

Comment: You can add an employee foreign key in your customer table. So you can control if a customer belongs to an employe. It may be the easier way to solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find using `hasPermission` convenient for such requirements. Specifically,

1. Enable method security by annotating a configuration class with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`
2. Fetch the customer in your controller, and call a service method, passing the customer.
3. Annotate the service method with `@PreAuthorize`

   ```
   @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#customer, 'edit')")
   public void updateCustomer(Customer customer, ...) {
   ...
   ```
4. You should have configured a `PermissionEvaluator`, like this:

   ```
   @Component
   public class PermissionEvaluatorImpl implements PermissionEvaluator {

   @Override
   public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth,
       Object entity, Object permission) {

           // return true only if auth has the given
           // permission for the customer.
           // Current user can be obtained from auth.
   }

   ...

   }
   ```
5. As a cleaner pattern, in the above method, you can delegate the permission checks to the entity classes, like this:

   ```
   BaseEntity baseEntity = (BaseEntity) entity;
   return entity.hasPermission(Util.getUser(auth), (String) permission);
   ```

See [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-permission-evaluator) for more details.