# Authorization in spring-security based on path variables

Tags: spring, spring-security

My use case is to authenticate & then authorize users based on @PathVariable parameters. I need to execute some custom code to authorize the principal. I'm not sure of the approach to take here -

1. I have implemented a custom AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter & AuthenticationProvider for authentication, which ends up granting roles to the principal. I can inspect the pathvariables in the servlet request (using HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE), and add additional authorities to the Authentication token. Then I can use the built-in hasRole, hasPermission expressions to implement access control.
2. I can extend WebSecurityExpressionRoot and implement a custom AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler and define my own expressions to be used in the intercept-url access-control expressions. I'm not sure how I can access the @PathVariables when defining custom methods in my WebSecurityExpressionRoot implementation.

Which approach is preferable, or is there another way to do this cleanly?

Answer (score 12):

I do have a solution. 
In a configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

I could have method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/student/{id}/**")
            .access("@guard.checkUserId(authentication,#id)");
}
```

while @guard in SpEL links to

```
@Component
public class Guard {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    public boolean checkUserId(Authentication authentication, int id) {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        System.out.println(name+" at "+id);
        User result = repo.findByUsername(name);
        return result != null && result.getPid() == id;
    }
}
```

In practice, the #id in SpEL can get the value extracted from {id} in the previous line. You can do whatever you want in checkUserId, and the return value decides whether the access to the path would be allowed.

Comment: I like the solution here, because you have a single point to implement authorization for all calls with a specific path. The problem is that you are not able to rely on authentication, because you are not able to have two rules (authencated() and access()) for one path. Or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 1):

A way I could imagine for this would be to capture the path variable in a parameter, using method level authorization, and then using `hasPermission`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870844/what-is-the-proper-way-to-restrict-the-access-of-some-data/31871741#31871741) has details about how to do it exactly - in case it would help.

Comment: The hasPermission api is a bit restrictive, for e.g. what if i need to access multiple path variables, or some other component of the api signature. That's why I want to define my own methods to use in the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

("/your-end-point/{yourReferenceId}/**")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).