# SpEL evaluation of path variable in WebsocketSecurityConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, jhipster, spring-el

I am running a JHipster 6.1.2 Gateway with Websockets and am trying to restrict access to a messaging topic, so that users can only subscribe to topics of the institution they belong to. So basically I want to perform a check on the `id` from the subscription path.

My current solution is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/44895369/4246074 and looks as follows:

**WebsocketSecurityConfiguration.java**:

```java
@Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        //...
        //User can only subscribe to own institution topic
        .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/institution.{id}")
        .access("@institutionIdGuard.checkInstitutionId(#id)")
        //...
    }
```

**InstitutionIdGuard.java**:

```java
@Component
public class InstitutionIdGuard {
    public boolean checkInstitutionId(Long institutionId) {

        //validation logic for institutionId would go here
        return true;
     }
```

The problem:
Apparently the SpEL expression can't access `{id}` from the path because i get a nullpointer error with the following log:

```
2019-08-08 10:30:08.367 ERROR 31097 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-1] o.s.w.s.m.StompSubProtocolHandler        : Failed to send client message to application via MessageChannel in session j2a0jlos. Sending STOMP ERROR to client.

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '@institutionIdGuard.checkInstitutionId(#id)'
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:146)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageFromClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:324)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.delegateMessages(AbstractSockJsSession.java:386)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.handleMessage(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.SockJsWebSocketHandler.handleTextMessage(SockJsWebSocketHandler.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(AbstractWebSocketHandler.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleTextMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$000(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.FrameHandler$7.run(FrameHandler.java:286)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer$1.call(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:170)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer$1.call(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:167)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer.invokeEndpointMethod(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:604)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer.invokeEndpointMethod(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:594)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.FrameHandler.invokeTextHandler(FrameHandler.java:266)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.FrameHandler.onFullTextMessage(FrameHandler.java:317)
    at io.undertow.websockets.core.AbstractReceiveListener$2.complete(AbstractReceiveListener.java:156)
    at io.undertow.websockets.core.AbstractReceiveListener$2.complete(AbstractReceiveListener.java:152)
    at io.undertow.websockets.core.BufferedTextMessage.read(BufferedTextMessage.java:105)
    at io.undertow.websockets.core.AbstractReceiveListener.readBufferedText(AbstractReceiveListener.java:152)
    at io.undertow.websockets.core.AbstractReceiveListener.bufferFullMessage(AbstractReceiveListener.java:90)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.FrameHandler.onText(FrameHandler.java:182)
    at io.undertow.websockets.core.AbstractReceiveListener.handleEvent(AbstractReceiveListener.java:44)
    at io.undertow.websockets.core.AbstractReceiveListener.handleEvent(AbstractReceiveListener.java:33)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedChannel$FrameReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractFramedChannel.java:951)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedChannel$FrameReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractFramedChannel.java:932)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:561)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '@institutionIdGuard.checkInstitutionId(#id)'
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30)
    at org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.MessageExpressionVoter.vote(MessageExpressionVoter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.MessageExpressionVoter.vote(MessageExpressionVoter.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor.preSend(ChannelSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorChain.applyPreSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:132)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method checkInstitutionId(null) cannot be found on type com.mycompany.websocketgateway.security.InstitutionIdGuard
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:225)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:134)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:54)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:390)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:300)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:26)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

I would be grateful for any ideas how to make my solution work or other other ways of performing checks in the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on the [Spring Security issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4469). Apparently before Spring Security 5.2 you can pass the implicit `message` variable to the SpEL expression

```
.simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/institution.*")
    .access("@institutionIdGuard.checkInstitutionId(authentication, message)")
```

Then in the verification method its possible to get the path from the message and do your own verification with it:

```
public boolean checkInstitutionId(Authentication authentication, Message<?> message) {
        StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        String topic = sha.getDestination();
        String id = topic.replace("/topic/institution/", "");

        //validation logic for institutionId would go here
        return true;
}
```

Spring Security 5.2 should have fixed the issue according to [this pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/6110).